# Were most of the Salvadorans granted TPS in 1990 staying legally or illegally in the US before that?

Tags: united-states, immigration, illegal-immigration, complementary-protection, el-salvador

Salvadorans are currently the largest group of TPS holders in the United States, although the Trump administration has decided to no longer extend their status, a decision that [resulted in a court challenge](https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2019/03/08/immigrants-temporary-protected-status-in-us/).

I want to know what was the immigration status of most TPS-granted Salvadorans before they got TPS. I.e. were most of them legally in the the US, e.g. on some other temporary visa/permit etc.? Or were they mostly illegal immigrants before getting TPS?

I'm asking this because in 1986 there was an [overt amnesty](https://abcnews.go.com/ABC_Univision/Politics/1986-amnesty/story?id=18971179) for illegal immigrants.